# Using "lpr" command to print text without text file on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

I can use the command to simply print an image using lpr command on windows.
However, how to use "lpr" printing a text (say "hello world") without creating a new text file everytime? It would be great if I can also dynamically set its fonts-size and name?
Thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you doing this from? You could just implement the LPR protocol, which is fairly simple.

Comment: Hi Rowland, I am now using vb.net, and I knew using PrintDocument is one of the way for printing, but my printer (XEROX DocuWide 6055) can automatically adjust the paper size for printing.
However, it is fine to know the command for printing text without text file only. Thank you.

Comment: There is [source available for an LPR client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12677/An-LPR-client-in-C) - it's relatively trivial to refactor to allow a `Stream` to be sent, rather than a file

Comment: whats the format of your image? .ps ou simple jpeg? whats your printer?